# MySql Disorder Result set using query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Good Evening,
I have a query like this:

```
SELECT @c:=@c+1 as Count, CurrentISP 
FROM (
  SELECT 'yahoo.com' as currentISP
    UNION ALL SELECT 'yahoo.com'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'gmail.com'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'gmail.com'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'hotmail.com'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'hotmail.com'
  ) t
INNER JOIN ( SELECT @c:=0 )  c
```

Which produces a result set as follows:

```
Count  CurrentISP
--
1   yahoo.com
2   yahoo.com
3   gmail.com
4   gmail.com
5   hotmail.com
6   hotmail.com
```

What I want to do is give this set an Ordering as follow:

```
1) yahoo.com
2) gmail.com
3) hotmail.com
4) maybe some ither Email Provider
5) when All providers are over start over again
6) yahoo.com etc etc
```

The reason I would like to do this, is because is to avoid spamming a certain provider with emails at the same time... So I can increase my sender score reputation back to 100%.

Comment: ?? you are intentionally select those twice.. why not just select them once? your question is not clear at all

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to do this in the application. Get all the providers, and then loop through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little hacky but you can order by a count for each time the name appears.. this will loop for as many records as you put in.

```
SELECT @D:=@D+1 AS Count, CurrentISP 
FROM 
    ( SELECT @C:=0, @A:=0, @B:=0, @D:=0 )  temp,
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (
            SELECT 'yahoo.com' AS currentISP
            UNION ALL SELECT 'yahoo.com'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'gmail.com'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'gmail.com'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'hotmail.com'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'hotmail.com'
        ) t
        ORDER BY
            CASE 
                WHEN currentISP='yahoo.com' THEN @A := @A + 1 
                WHEN currentISP='gmail.com' THEN @B := @B + 1  
                WHEN currentISP='hotmail.com' THEN @C := @C + 1  
            END DESC
    ) AS t
```

this is what the query returns: [IMAGE](http://screencast.com/t/Z55S2SdHO)

Comment: You are Imba :) Thanks a lot mister.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order a list of duplicate values, maybe something like this would be better

```
select currentIsp
from 
    (
        select 1 as n 
        union select 2
        -- Add as many unique numbers you need
    ) as a,
    (
         select 'yahoo.com' as currentISP
         union select 'gmail.com'
         union select 'hotmail.com'
         -- More UNION queries with unique ISP names
    ) as t
order by a.n, t.currentIsp
```

(I don't think you need a `Count` column, but you can add it if you want)